# After 5 minutes, audio dramatically goes out of sync for rest of video. Shifting that audio section around fixes problem only for a few seconds

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, audio, software-recommendation

At the 5min:12sec mark in [this Facebook Live video](https://www.facebook.com/CitizensMediaTV/videos/1112194702194246/), there is a glitch/freeze. The audio goes out for a few seconds, and then comes back in. But when it comes back in, it is terribly out of sync. I have [downloaded the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqy1pdYRVIo), and am trying to fix it. I will ultimately be uploading it to my YouTube account.

Unfortunately, shifting that section of audio around fixes the problem briefly, but it soon returns. In other words, it seems that the length of the video is now a different than it's audio track.I tried the advice in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKskUvNxxUE) without success.

How do I re-sync the audio and video tracks?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to lay the video back out to tape then to recapture? This would be the quickest fix for the issue. Or differing audio sampling rates, 32k, 44.1k, and or 48k..

Answer (score 0):

You probably have mismatched framerates. This can cause audio drift. The solution for that would be to slow or speed the audio up slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the source was; it could be that as well. For instance, PPro, once it reached CS6, no longer handled HDV content and there was audio drift over time... it was a big problem, I am not sure if it was ever fixed.

Just throwing this out there, but it could be the source codec not playing fair with whatever module FB uses to transcode it's video for playback.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the part where the whole video freezes as lost but if you simply import it to Premiere Pro and split the video from the audio you can then cut in the audio layer and move it to where the audio syncs.

If there is a change in speed I would recommend to change the speed of the video in stead of the audio.